# Как работает a ^ b в reduce?

Tags: javascript

```js
function stray(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);
}

console.log(stray([1, 2, 1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Банка `^` это операция xor [побитовое исключающее или](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR). Функция [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) выполняет callback над всеми элементами массива, каждый раз подставляя результат предыдущего выполнения. Т.е. для вашего примера, результат будет эквивалентен следующему:

```
(1 ^ 2) ^ 1 //2
```

Если бы массив был длиннее, например `1,2,3,4,5`, то таким:

```
(((1 ^ 2) ^ 3) ^ 4) ^ 5 //1
```

На выходе получится одно значение, которое можно с натяжкой назвать хэшем или контрольной суммой массива. Но для чего она может быть нужна это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @Seona16 пожалуйста. Не забудьте отменить ответ как принятый, если он решил вашу проблему.

Comment: `(1 ^ 2) ^ 1 //3` если в комментарии указан результат - то он неверный

Comment: @Grundy не то скопировал видимо, поправил ответ, спасибо

Comment: Натяжка просто гигантская. Ни хэши, ни контрольные суммы не считают коммутативными и ассоциативными операциями.